# Unable to create folder and paste in Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

In my computer I have many drives I installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot. The problem is I am not able to modify (write) Windows drive files.

```
: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foldername’: Read-only file system
```

Comment: thanks for ur comment...how can i install ntfs-3g in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: with: `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

Comment: its not working can u give me step by step process

Comment: i am using ubuntu 18.04 lts 64 bit

Comment: `ntfs-3g` is installed by default in Ubuntu these days, so that won't solve this problem

Comment: [unlock ntfs partition](https://superuser.com/questions/964402/is-there-anyway-to-unlock-hibernated-ntfs-partition#964459) and [unable to mount windows partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation#145904) might help. The problem could be that your ntfs partition is in hibernation state. This happens when windows doesn't shutdown correctly or if windows was in hibernation an the power got cut. If that is the case I would recommend booting into windows and then shutting it down completely again.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem is the `sudo` in the mounting for the share, which is required for the mounting command.  After the mounting, the share belongs to `root` and you can't write to it.  You can remedy this by providing with `uid=[your Ubuntu uid]`.  This is proving write access to you.

You also have to make sure that the user under `username= and password=` have write permission provided by the Windows server.

Make sure you include these parameters in your mounting options:

- uid=[your Ubuntu UID #]
- username=[Real user on the Windows 10 machine]

**Example:**

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username="ljames",uid=1001 //192.168.15.84/c /mnt
```

Windows 10 have an option to login with your email address that is registered with Microsoft.  In this case (which you may already know since you're able to mount the share), but for general knowledge, this will be done by:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username="ljames@outlook.com",uid=1001 //192.168.15.84/c /mnt
```

There are many options that can be specified in the command line (or in the `/etc/fstab` file) such as:

- file_mode=0660
- dir_mode=0775

Those options goes after the `-o` options argument, separated by the comma.